# Is it possible to change this code so that its loops are removed and replace with tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I used the following code as part of my deep learning algorithm.
But due to the existence of loops, its execution time is very long.
Can you implement it only with tensorflow's methods?

```py
def build_reward(self):
    self.permutations = tf.stack([tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(tf.range(self.batch_size,dtype=tf.int32),1),[1,self.max_length+1]),self.tour],2)
    output_list = [] 
    if self.is_training==True:
        self.ordered_input_ = tf.gather_nd(self.input_,self.permutations)
        self.ordr = tf.gather_nd(self.order_,self.permutations)
    else:
        self.ordered_input_ = tf.gather_nd(tf.tile(self.input_,[self.batch_size,1,1]),self.permutations)
        self.ordr = tf.gather_nd(tf.tile(self.order_,[self.batch_size,1]),self.permutations)


    def Tca(indx, l, bth):
        t = 0.0
        n = 0
        f = 0
        p = 0
        result = 0.0
        for i in range(self.max_length):
            t = tf.math.floor(self.ordered_input_[bth,i,indx])
            p = tf.cond(tf.logical_and((tf.logical_or(tf.logical_or(tf.logical_or(tf.math.equal(t,1.0),
                                                    tf.math.equal(t,5.0)),
                                                    tf.math.equal(t,6.0)),
                                                    tf.math.equal(t,8.0))),tf.math.not_equal(i,l)), 
                        lambda:i, lambda:-1) 
            n += tf.cond(tf.math.not_equal(p,-1), lambda:1, lambda:0)
            f += tf.cond(
                tf.logical_and(
                    tf.math.not_equal(p,-1),
                    tf.math.greater(
                        tf.math.count_nonzero(
                            tf.math.equal(
                                self.ordr[bth,:l],
                                self.ordr[bth,p]
                            )
                        ), 0
                    )
                ), lambda: 1, lambda:0
            )
        result = tf.cond(tf.math.equal(n,f), lambda:0.0, lambda:1.0)
        return result



    for b in range(0,self.batch_size):
        fuse = 0
        rsize = tf.math.floor(self.ordered_input_[b,0,self.ordr[b,0]]) 
        rgstr = tf.math.ceil(
            tf.math.multiply(
                tf.math.subtract(
                    self.ordered_input_[b,0,self.ordr[b,1]],
                    tf.math.floor(self.ordered_input_[b,0,self.ordr[b,1]])
                ), 10
            )
        )
        r = 0
        rwrd = 0.0 
        dt = 0.0 
        for i in range(self.max_length-1):
            fuse = 0
            dt = tf.math.floor(self.ordered_input_[b,i,self.ordr[b,i+1]])
            r = tf.math.ceil(
                    tf.math.multiply(
                        tf.math.subtract(
                            self.ordered_input_[b,(i+1),self.ordr[b,(i+2)]],
                            tf.math.floor(self.ordered_input_[b,(i+1),self.ordr[b,(i+2)]])
                        ), 10
                    )
                )
            rwrd += tf.truediv(dt,10.0) 
            pnlty = tf.cond(
                        tf.math.not_equal(dt,10.0), 
                        lambda:Tca(self.ordr[b,i+1],(i+1), b), lambda:1.0
                    )
            fuse = tf.cond(
                       tf.logical_and(
                           tf.math.equal(pnlty,0.0),
                           tf.logical_or(
                               tf.math.equal(dt,1.0),
                               tf.math.equal(dt,3.0)
                           )
                       ),
                       lambda:1, lambda:0
                   )
            rgstr = tf.cond(
                        tf.math.not_equal(fuse,1),
                        lambda:r,
                        lambda:rgstr
                    )
            rgstr += tf.cond(tf.math.equal(fuse,1), lambda:r, lambda:0.0)
            pnlty += tf.cond(tf.math.not_equal(fuse,1), lambda:1.0, lambda:0.0)
            pnlty += tf.cond(
                        tf.logical_and(
                            tf.math.greater(rgstr,self.register),
                            tf.math.equal(fuse,1)
                        ),
                        lambda:1.0, lambda:0.0
                    )
            rgstr = tf.cond(tf.math.greater(rgstr,self.register), 
                        lambda:r, lambda:rgstr)
            rwrd += pnlty

        output_list.append(rwrd)
```

As you can see, the code consists of three nested loops.
This will greatly increase the codes performance.
I'm looking for a way to reduce its run time.
One of my options could be to remove the loops.
But I do not think it is possible for the logic behind this code.
I will be grateful if anyone can guide me in this regard.
Also, if someone can remove some of these loops, it will help me a lot.

Comment: Do you really define a function inside your method, or is that just an indentation issue from copying your code here?

Comment: I define a function inside my method. "reward" is a method of a class and "Tca" is a function in it.